# Is it possible to define initial parameter arguments for Java webapp listeners?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-listeners

In a web application's web.xml file, one can define initial parameters for servlets and filters by using the init-param element.  Parameters defined here can then be retrieved by calling getServletConfig().  It does not seem possible to do the same with listeners, as the DTD only defines the listener-class element there.

I would really rather not resort to having a bunch of random properties files (or even worse, more XML configuration ones) inside of my webapp, but I'm not sure how I can otherwise pass data to my listeners during initialization.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define [initialisation parameters](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/ServletWebXMLContextInitParameter.htm) for the context as a whole, and get those from the ServletContext object.

If your listener implements [ServletContextListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) then you can grab the initialisation parameters when receiving the contextInitialized event.

Comment: I never knew that these could be defined in the web.xml -- but it's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!